# Magento 2 : Sample Data not Showing

Tags: installation, sample-data, magento2.2-dev

I Installed Magento 2.2.0-dev through git clone.

I tried installing sample data by using Magento's method of cloning repositories http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data-before-clone.html#sample-clone

The sample data is installed and I can see everything in admin.

On front end, pages are blank.
When I go to a category page I can see product filters but I cannot see any of products - content is blank.

When I run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` it seems to upgrade everything just fine but then at end it says

`Please re-run Magento compile command. Use command "setup:di:compile"
Start import:
Nothing to import`

I checked in list of modules and `Module 'Magento_SampleData':` is in list

What could I be missing?

**UPDATE:**

I set the store to development mode and then the items show.
Only in production mode does it not show the items.
Is sample data only meant to work in development mode?

Comment: Check the permissions of "var" and "pub" folder and run below commands aagain.  - php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: all I get is "We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email."

Comment: Please try to re-run your sample data again.

Comment: Thanks, will try. More important then getting it to show, I would like to know why it's currently not showing